# Как отменить данное свойство CSS?

Tags: css, svg

```
svg g, svg path {fill: inherit}
```

И везде так и требуется. Но как быть если в одном месте мне надо что бы SVG имел тот же `fill` что и в документе ( там градиент поэтому задать через CSS не вариант ) . Как задать что бы в одном месте `svg g` и `svg path` имели `fill` из самого `.svg` файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если я правильно понял задачу, то открываете SVG в редакторе, например VSCODE. и у `g` либо `path` у значения fill ставите `!important`. В результате у данного svg будет цвет исходный. Фото ниже.

[image: Изменение стиля]

Comment: Спасибо это гениально